# Build Flutter Apps for iOS with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, swiftui

i am a little bit confused. I am developing flutter application and now, the first time, I have to deal with the iOS thing...I already knew that I need an apple device, but now, I am wondering if it is necessary to buy a macBook caused by xCode to build the app or if a iPad would also fit with SwiftUI, just for building the application.

I would be happy about feedback, if the iPad is also an option.

Greetings,
CaptainN3ro

Comment: Mac is generally used by developers build iOS apps. It is technically possible to build using iPad but I haven't tried to use an iPad for building apps.

Comment: I agree with @user1046037. While Apple has now made is possible [to build SwiftUI apps on iPad](https://support.apple.com/guide/playgrounds-ipad/create-an-app-playground-itc2207c0870/ipados), Xcode is still by far preferred for building apps, and it is the only way that I have built them (on a Mac, as Xcode does not support iPad).

Comment: Okay, thank you! So I have to buy a MacBook.